# Getting Twitter data from RoR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

I have a RoR 3 application and I'm trying to integrate it with Twitter. So what do I need?

I need to count how many tweets with a certain hashtag (like #awesometag) were tweeted by users that follow me.

There are many ways to do this, as I saw while searching online. However, I want to know the most reliable way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Twitter gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter) for all this stuff. If im not mistaken there is a Search class for doing what you want. [More info](http://twitter.rubyforge.org/) about this gem